# Using hero animation with GetX Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation, flutter-getx

Does anybody have experience using the Hero animation with the GetX Route-Managment? I followed the instructions in https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/animations/hero-animations and use `Get.toNamed()`to navigate between my routes but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've been using `Getx` for quite some time, and I don't suggest trying to get the hero animations with `Getx`'s route manager, because the `Hero` widget can link two widgets with the same `tag` using a [HeroControllerScope](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/HeroControllerScope-class.html), which is an `InheritedWidget`.

the `InheritedWidget` can be found in a place by the `BuildContext` where it's looked up.

and `Getx` **break this rule**, the `Get.to()` and `Get.toNamed()` navigate to new screens using a pre-set `BuildContext`.

so this will only get you into trouble, instead, think about using the `Navigator` widget with a `BuildContext`, to get `Hero` animations executing fine.